# concurrency in data fetching while the previous batch of data is being processed

Tags: python-asyncio

I am trying to create a loop of two steps: (1) fetching data, and (2) data processing.

Obviously, step 2 of iteration i, depends on the output of step 1 from iteration i. However, while step (2) of iteration i is running, step (1) of iteration i+1 can be processed.

One more requirement is that concurrency for step (2) from different iterations is not allowed due to memory limitations.

Can I be helped with a sample script using python asyncio library?

Answer (score 0):

The general formula is:

```
async def fetch_data(...):
   ...

async def process_data(...):
   ...

async def mytask(source):
    # these are executed in series; 
    data = await fetch_data(source)
    await process_data(data)

async def main(sources):
    # if sources are limited and not a lot (~ < 10000):
    tasks = {asyncio.create_task(mytask(source) for source in sources)} 
    # and here, all the calls are made concurrently:
    results = await asyncio.gather(tasks)
```

If your data sources are streaming from somewhere, or you have a whole lot of sources, you will need some strategy to create then in batches. Not hard to do, but not explained here. But the main point in your question is encoded in the example: parts of each task that have to be executed in series, are better written as a handler function that just do that - in this case, the `mytask` function - and then you paralelize the calls to it.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is a great sample code but I think it is slightly different from what I was looking for. I believe this code violates the requirement of no concurrent `process_data` runs. Essentially, the only concurrency I want to allow is process_data of iteration i and fetch_data of iteration i+1.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

Do the first fetch outside the loop.

Then enter a loop where the next fetch and the processing of the previous data run concurrently.

```
data = await fetch_data()
while True:
    fetch_task = asyncio.create_task(fetch_data())
    await process_data(data)
    data = await fetch_task
```